# getfield Custom field

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

I'm trying to get the value return by my field for the normal field, it's working without problem but for the custom, I receive this error message: 
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

So here the piece of code that I'm trying:

```
   private void Application_WindowSelectionChange(MSProject.Window Window, MSProject.Selection sel, object selType)
        {
            MSProject.Task task;
            MSProject.PjField pjField;
            if (sel.Tasks != null)
            {
                task = sel.Application.ActiveSelection.Tasks[1];
                pjField = sel.Application.Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList[1]);
                string StringField = task.GetField(pjField);
                sel.Application.StatusBar = pjField;
                bool flag = false;
                string[] split = StringField.Split(' ');
            }
        }
```

there is something which is very weird, for some entreprise custom field return a value (188776530) but the others return me an error message

any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which of these lines throws the exception you encounter?

Comment: there is no logic behind, sometimes a cost can be returned, sometimes not
It's really weird but normally it can't return custom field entreprise

Comment: Try declaring pjField as a 32-bit integer rather than PjField. For custom fields, it won't be one of the intrinsic PjField constants.

Comment: But I have also normal field
I tried to build a new project with many customfield and here it's always working, except two times

Comment: Not sure why you have sel.Application.Application (repeated). Also, typically it's easier to have a global variable for the application object. For example: `MSProject.Application projApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`. Then `pjField = projApp.FieldNameToFieldConstant(projApp.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList[1]);`

Comment: I've done some tests, so if I put all my custom field in a normal view like task sheet, I have no problem everything will work
But when I use custom views, there the problem started, sometines I have a customfield sometimes an error message
Weird no?